# Does having a shared_ptr member break the CopyConstructible contract?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, copy-constructor

I just had an argument over at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/165395/138884) where it was stated that a class that has a `std::shared_ptr` member would break the [CopyConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible) contract, specifically:

> The following expressions must be valid and have their specified
>   effects
>
> T u = v;
>
> The value of v is unchanged

The reasoning was that copying would change the source object by increasing the *reference count* of the `shared_ptr`, but my counter-argument is that the reference count is stored separately from the `shared_ptr`. Changing the reference count is a side effect, but the reference does not state that side effects outside of the object being copied are forbidden.

But then I'm not a language lawyer so I might be wrong.

What is right according to the C++ standard?

Comment: `std::shard_ptr` is copy constructible. Do you have a specific example why that shouldn't work?

Comment: While the `std::shared_ptr` object itself will be modified (or rather its shared control block) the object being pointed to is not. Here it's important to distinguish wrapper objects (like the shared pointer object) and the wrapped object (the object being pointed to by the shared pointer object).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't have such an example, that's why I'm asking. It's a theoretical question about the language spec. Having a copy constructor does not necessarily fulfill the CopyConstructible *concept* if the contract is violated.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude _While the std::shared_ptr object itself will be modified (or rather its shared control block)_ ... This could be seen as an argument that the contract is broken. In the expression `T u = v;` where both arguments are `shared_ptr` the *value of v* would be the `shared_ptr` itself, not the object being pointed to.

Comment: @juanchopanza How does your comment help answer the question?

Comment: @juanchopanza Comments should be used to clarify the question or point out mistakes; in this way they help to answer the question. How does your comment fall into this category?

Comment: Fine. Removed..

Comment: _"All specializations of shared_ptr meet the requirements of CopyConstructible, CopyAssignable, and LessThanComparable and are contextually convertible to bool."_ source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: Current draft standard: _"Specializations of shared_ptr shall be CopyConstructible, CopyAssignable, and LessThanComparable,
allowing their use in standard containers"_   source:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf   __23.11.2.2 [2]__

Comment: Do you like chocolate or vanilla? It's fine if it's fine **to you**.

Comment: @RichardCritten "_"Specializations of shared_ptr shall be CopyConstructible, CopyAssignable_" That's just one POV. It's CopyConstructible if you say it's CopyConstructible, otherwise it's not.

Comment: @curiousguy thats my reading of the standard as well.  It is mandated to be all of the above .... so even if it isn't it is.

Comment: @RichardCritten If you consider the reference count part of the "value" of a reference counting smart ptr, then the copy ctor of the smart ptr doesn't perform copy as it changes the (const qualified) source. It's your own call.

Answer (score 2):

> The value of v is unchanged

The value of an object is what you say it is.

> The reasoning was that copying would change the source object by increasing the reference count of the shared_ptr, but my counter-argument is that the reference count is stored separately from the shared_ptr.

Where the count is stored, or *whether it is even stored somewhere*, is outside the scope of the standard.